# How to list latest replies in a specific forum category using Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am working on a forum. I have the following model structure in Laravel and Eloquent:

```
Category hasMany Threads
Thread hasMany Posts
Thread hasManyThrough Reply, Post
Post hasMany Replies
```

I can list latest 5 replies against a post using:

```
$recentReplies = $post->replies()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

I can even list latest 5 replies against a thread as well using hasManyThrough relation using:

```
$recentReplies = $thread->replies()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

**My question is how can i list latest 5 replies against a category?**

Following doesn't work:

```
$recentReplies = $category->threads()->replies()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

I have also tried the following but failed:

```
$recentReplies = $category->threads->replies()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

I have the following sample model structure:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function threads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Thread');
    }

}

class Thread extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Reply', 'Post');
    }

}

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Reply');
    }

}

class Reply extends Eloquent {
    // NOTE: belongsTo method exists in all models
}
```

Thanks in advance for all of your time and effort?

regards

Ahmed Khan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this trick:

```
$recentReplies = null;

// let's find 5 replies for category with $categoryId
Category::with(['threads.replies' => function ($q) use (&$recentReplies) {

   $recentReplies = $q->latest()->take(5)->get();
}])->find($categoryId);
```

Comment: Thank you Jarek, I replaced threds with threads in your code sample and this trick did work and solved my issue. and sorry for the late reply as I didn't receive any notification for this reply in my email box. don't know why. Any how my issues is solved now.